# Automatically place numbers in cell Microsoft Office Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

```
|   | A      | B         | C         | D         |
|---|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 1 | Number | First     | Second    | Third     |
|---|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 2 | 6      | 1, 2 or 3 | 4, 5 or 6 | 7, 8 or 9 |
```

In the above example, `6` (in `A2`) should appear under `Second`. If `3` is in `A2` rather than `6`, then `3` should appear under `First`, and so forth.

Is there a formula for this to use in First, Second and Third?

Comment: What? What do you mean appear? Are the "1, 2 or 3" statements already in row 2? Where would the 6 go? Would it replace "4, 5 or 6" or would it go in `C3`? What happens to the 6 in `A2`? Does it remain or is it deleted?

Answer (score 3):

In cell B2:

```
=IF(AND(A2>=1,A2<=3),A2,"")
```

This tests if cell A2's content is in the range 1-3 and displays it if it is, or otherwise displays an empty string (a blank).

Apply similar formulae in cells C2 and D2.